# How to replace all equal signs with forward slashes using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to remove all instances of the "=" sign and replace it with the "/" sign. Using htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^=]*)=([^=]*)=(.*) /$1/$2/$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^=]*)=([^=]*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```